# Animate in order with angular and animate.css

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation

Im trying to add some animation to my angular application with animate css.
I have a directive with transclude = true, so I can insert sub directives inside a parent directive.

I wrote some custom code to add the animation as I had some hard time using ng-show in my case, as I have to seperate modules that I dont want to depend on each other, one is menu module that represent a menu, and the other is security module, that contains a directive that shows or hides directives depending on the users role.

My role directive looks somthing like this:

```
(function(angular) {
'use strict';
angular.module('angSecurity')
.directive('angSecurityRole', angSecurityRole);
////////////
function angSecurityRole($timeout, PubSub) {
    var DEFAULT_ANIMATION = 'fade';
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: false,
        multiElement: true,
        controller: 'angLoginCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'alc',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            var vm = scope.alc;
            scope.$watch(function() {return attr.angSecurityRole;}, ngShowWatchAction);
            var subscriptions = [];
            //listen to role changing events
            subscriptions.push(PubSub.subscribe('event-user-logged-out' , ngShowWatchAction));
            subscriptions.push(PubSub.subscribe('event-user-logged-in'  , ngShowWatchAction));
            //remove subscriptions when destroyed
            scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                angular.forEach(subscriptions, function(subscription) {
                    PubSub.unsubscribe(subscription);
                });
            });
            //////////////
            function ngShowWatchAction(newVal, oldVal) {
                var changed      = newVal !== oldVal;
                var actualRole   = vm.getRole();
                var requiredRole = attr.angSecurityRole;
                var show         = requiredRole === actualRole;

                var animation    = getAnimation();
                if (show) {
                    element.css('display', 'block');
                }
                element.addClass(animation);
                $timeout(function() {
                    element.removeClass(animation);
                    if (!show) {
                        element.css('display', 'none');
                    }
                }, 1000);
                ////////////////
                function getAnimation() {
                    var defaultAnimation = DEFAULT_ANIMATION + (show ? 'In' : 'Out');
                    var animation = null;
                    if (!!attr.animation && attr.animation !== null) {
                        animation = scope.$eval(attr.animation);
                        animation = show ? animation.enter : animation.leave;
                    }
                    return 'animated ' + animation ?  animation : DEFAULT_ANIMATION;               
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
})(angular);
```

And the menu directives are:

```
(function(angular) {
'use strict';
angular.module('angMenu')
    .directive('angMenu', angMenu);
////////////
function angMenu() {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'app/modules/menuModule/templates/menu.tpl.html',
        controller: 'menuController',
        controllerAs: 'mc',
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var vm = scope.mc;
        }
    };
}
})(angular);
```

and:

```
(function(angular) {
'use strict';
angular.module('angMenu')
    .directive('angMenuItem', angMenuItemDirective);
////////////
function angMenuItemDirective() {
    return {
        require:    '^angMenu',
        replace:    true,
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'app/modules/menuModule/templates/menuItem.tpl.html',
        scope: {
            label: '@',
            icon:  '@',
            route: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
            var vm = ctrl; //ctrl reffers to angMenu (parent controller)
            scope.isActive = function () {
                return el === vm.activeItem;
            };
            el.bind('click', function(ev) {
                ev.stopPropagation();
                ev.preventDefault();
                ctrl.setActiveItem(el);
                ctrl.setRoute(scope.route);
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
}
})(angular);
```

I want the animation of the the transcluded elements to occur after the parent animation, how can U do that?

Answer (score 0):

custom parent animation, when parent finish animating emit event let children know

child directive use require get parent controller and when parent controller emits finish animation begin your child animation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-

code for custom your own animation from https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations

```js
myModule.directive('my-directive', ['$animate', function($animate) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.on('click', function() {
      if(element.hasClass('clicked')) {
        $animate.removeClass(element, 'clicked');
      } else {
        $animate.addClass(element, 'clicked');
      }
    });
  };
}]);
```